# Struts multiple file upload with Dyna Action Forms (Struts 1)

Tags: file-upload, struts, struts-1

I need to upload multiple files on a single page.  With DynaAction forms you must specify the "name" of each one.  I need this to be dynamic.  I believe that I can use an array/list to get a bunch of files, but I can't match the files to anything specific.

A map would be perfect, but I am afraid I cannot figure out the "key" part of the map.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I researched and spent 3 hours trying different stuff.  There is a dearth of info on the web concerning this.  Lots of unanswered questions.  Now that Struts 1 is sunset, there will probably be no more info, so I thought I would add a nail to the coffin...

I discovered that I was making this a bigger deal than I needed to.  With the help of these two pages:

[Building a controller](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html)

[Index Properties](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/indexedprops.html)

I figured out that what you really want to do is use a Map to store the FormFile Objects.  Most of the documentation I found was relying on Model Objects but I was using DynaForms.  So the Struts-config.xml looks like this:

```
<form-property name="theFiles" type="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

The JSP looks like this:

```
 <c:forEach items="${userForm.map.roleChanges}" var="changeMap" varStatus="status"> 
...
    <html:file property="theFile(${changeMap.key.roleName})"  styleId="theFile" />
...     
</c:forEach>
```

The secret sauce is the property:  theFiles(${changeMap.key.roleName}).  Since theFiles is a Map, Struts needs a key, and you use the syntax above to get it in the map.  The Java to get the map is as follows:

```
Map fileMap =  (Map)userForm.get("theFile");
```

This is a Map of FormFile objects.  Sweet as can be.

I got hung up because I never used the ArrayList/Map stuff before.  It is quite simple (as it should be. Also, there is lots of talk about the "index" parameter on some Struts tags.  I fiddled around with it for a while, but could not get it to work.  I think it is because of DynaForm.  Not sure...